# Нужно ли в данном случае тире перед словом "есть"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Палатка (–) есть, то-то и то-то (–) есть (в смысле "имеется" / "в наличии" и т. п.)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно перед глаголом "есть" в значении "наличествует", "имеется" никакие знаки не ставятся.

***Счастье есть**, его не может не быть.*

*И теперь я точно знала, что **счастье есть**, что счастье — это просто.* [А. В. Жвалевский, Е. Пастернак. Время всегда хорошее (2009)]

*― жену уже не вернешь, но **сын есть, квартира есть, евроремонт есть, дача есть, машина есть, валюта есть.*** [Елена и Валерий Гордеевы. Не все мы умрем (2002)]

Но Ваш случай похож на список, где "есть" выступает в качестве галочки-отметки или плюсика, поэтому тире может иметь место, чтобы было нагляднее.

Палатка – есть
Котелок – есть
Рюкзак – есть
Пластиковая посуда – есть
Хорошее настроение – да!

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях (пересчёт, **несколько элементов**) тире ставится, потому что логическое ударение чётко и выражено падает на подлежащее. При наличии связки такого ударения уже нет и тире не требуется:
*Палатка у нас есть, то-то и то-то у нас тоже есть.*

Примечание: тире требуется, когда **смысл — "есть или нет"** (именно тогда присутствует сильное ударение), а не просто перечисление того, что есть, как в третьем примере Александра.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.